# Cannot convert type () to type AnnotationView

Tags: arrays, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

After much looking, it seems that If I want to correlate a tableView indexPath to an Annotation array, I have to check for similar features. Therefore, I'm deciding to check if the Pin array (of pin class) has a pin with a title equal to the name of the selected tableCell.

However, whenever I set up my function like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let restaurant = restaurantArray[indexPath.row]
    let restaurantName = restaurant.value(forKey: "Name") as!String ?
      if pinArray.contains(pin.title = restaurantName) {
      print("Found")
    }
    else {
      print("Nope")
    }
}
```

I am unable to see if the Pin array contains a pin with a title equal to restaurantName. Whether their be issues with bool, optionals, or other, I'm still trying to figure out how to find a pin with the same title as restaurantName.

Comment: Can you please describe what is the type of `restaurantArray` and `pinArray` in your context?

Comment: restaurantArray is full of CKRecords and PinArray is full of MKAnnotations via a pin class.

Comment: It should be `pinArray.contains(where: {$0.title = restaurantName})`. But the code is not needed any more. [If you make the `pinArray` consistent with `restaurantArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219801/6541007). You should better show what you really want to do with all relevant code instead of showing up some small part with wrong solution.

Comment: You are mixing up assign (`=`) and equality (`==`) operator: `if pinArray.contains(where: {$0.title == restaurantName})`. And force unwrapping an optional to an optional is meaningless `value(forKey: "Name") as! String`.

Comment: Awesome. Two remaining questions - what is $0 and what is it used for? I've only seen/come across it recently. Secondly, how would I use the pin that was equal to the restaurantName in the actual if statement?

Comment: `$0` is a placeholder for the actual array element. It's used in a simplified closure syntax instead of `{ (element) -> Bool in return element.title ==  restaurantName }`